# Javascript download csv without clicking

Tags: javascript, csv, download, click

I am trying to automate the downloading of a csv file using Javascript. Below is the Javascript that I have. I am trying to eliminate the HMTL at the bottom as the Javascript will be in a for loop and I want the file to download every time the for loop runs.

```
function convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(args) {
    var result, ctr, keys, columnDelimiter, lineDelimiter, data;

    data = args.data || null;
    if (data == null || !data.length) {
        return null;
    }

    columnDelimiter = args.columnDelimiter || ',';
    lineDelimiter = args.lineDelimiter || '\n';

    keys = Object.keys(data[0]);

    result = '';
    result += keys.join(columnDelimiter);
    result += lineDelimiter;

    data.forEach(function(item) {
        ctr = 0;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            if (ctr > 0) result += columnDelimiter;

            result += item[key];
            ctr++;
        });
        result += lineDelimiter;
    });

    return result;
}

window.downloadCSV3 = function(args) {
    var data, filename, link;

    var csv = convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV({
        data: allTheData
    });
    if (csv == null) return;

    filename = args.filename || 'export.csv';

    if (!csv.match(/^data:text\/csv/i)) {
        csv = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csv;
    }
    data = encodeURI(csv);

    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', data);
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    link.click();
}
```

And this is what the HTML looks like

```
<a href='#' id='link3' onclick='downloadCSV3({ filename: "file-id.csv" });'>Download CSV</a>
```

Is there a way to not have to deal with the HTML, but to instead download the file in the Javascript? There will be a for loop running around the download which is why I would like to not have a click.

Comment: you can use a tool like https://github.com/rndme/download

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden iframe and instruct the server to set the file MIME type to some random nonsense. This will cause the browser to default to "application/octet-stream", which causes the browser to prompt you to download.

```
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>

<script>
document.getElementById("frame").style.display = "none";
function Download(ref) {
document.getElementById('frame').src = ref;
};
</script>
```